Making python script install required packages using pip ( for school project )
I may ask something that could be answered with some google searches but because I did not find any clear answer I am posting this thread in case anybody is there to help me with this problem.
I am making a python project as an assignment for a computer science class and the professor told me that I can use any packages that I can find ( as long as they are free ). The issue is that me and many other students are concerned that the professor will not sit through each source code of the students and install the packages themselves. So we would really like to find a way to make the python script/code check if the package is installed and if not then install it, maybe by importing os and running "py -m pip install foo" or something.
I did not find any solution.

Just create a requirements.txt file.  That is the current standard way to document your dependencies.

+1 James, some IDEs will take care of automatically installing whatever is specified in the requirements file

Here's a simplified version:
Begin by creating a virtual environment in the same directory as your main.py file:
python3 -m venv <virtual_environment_name>
source <virtual_environment_path>/bin/activate

Next, create a requirements.txt file in the same directory and list all the libraries and packages needed. Finally, run the command:
pip install -r requirements.txt
If a library or package is already installed, it will be indicated during installation.

Python will already tell you if a dependency is missing when running your program, so there is no need to 'check'.
However, you can do a python -m pip freeze (or py -m pip freeze on Windows) to get a list of all the lib you used + the version and then paste it in a requirements.txt file.
Then just type python -m pip install -r requirements.txt and it will install everything for you, you're teacher can then do that ! Hope it helped
NB : python -m pip freeze > requirements.txt will get the libs and make it a requirements.txt file if you want

NB2: Do the 'python -m pip freeze' in the repo of your program

So what you could do is use an error handling, as well as storing all the needed modules In a dict.
firstly, Imagine you need the pyyaml module, but the way to import it is import yaml. as you can see, the name is different, so we'll use a dict.
Here is an example of a module dict:
modules = {
    "foo": "Foo", 
    "bar": "Bar", 
    "yaml": "pyyaml"
} 

One way to describe this code is that it's a module dict, where each module is paired with the name that is used to install it through pip (a lot of the time it's usually the same though) .
Now, it's time to setup the checking loop:
import os
for m in modules:
    try:
        globals()[m] = __import__(m)
    except ModuleNotFoundError:
        print("Module %s not found, installing it" % m) 
        os.system("pip install %s" % modules[m]) 
        globals()[m] = __import__(m)

That should be it, but tell me of there is anything wrong as I'm literally walking while writing.
finally, You just have to add your needed module and there pip-installing equivalent in the modules dict.
Edit:
I have a smaller version too:
import os

def fail_safe_import(module, pip_version=None):
    try:
        return __import__(module) 
    except ModuleNotFoundError:
        os.popen("pip install " + (pip_version or module)) 
        // the above code can be modified
        //To match the path and version of python
        return __import__(module)

//And now, use it as this:
//for example 
yaml = fail_safe_import("yaml", "pyyaml")
psutil = fail_safe_import("psutil")
// Or whatever you want.

